# Have Horizontal Scrollbar Appear For Flex Element

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a calculator, and I'm designing the area where the output is displayed.

If the output is longer than the display, I want a horizontal scroll bar to appear, so the user can see all of it.

I also want the characters to appear from right to left as they are entered, like a typical calculator.

```css
#calculator {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 30%;
}

#display {
  border: 2px solid rgba(219, 93, 46, 0.918);
  display: flex;
  height: 11%;
  width: 96%;
  margin: auto;
}

#display-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 7vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="App">
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="calc-header">
      My Calculator
    </div>

    <div id="display">
      <div id="display-text">
        1+2+3-9+3-9+3-9+5*5+8-15+66*3
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="calc-inputs">
      Buttons will go here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now, there is no horizontal scrollbar.  When I try overflow-x: auto;, same thing.

When I try overflow-x: scroll, I lose the flex-end properties and the characters start showing left to right.

Comment: Try putting the `overflow: auto` on the `#display` style and also add `word-wrap: break-word`, also, you're flexing both divs, just flex the parent div and let the child div be `block`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I applied your suggestions, and a horizontal scrollbar actually appeared!  However, `justify-content: flex-end;`  seems to be getting ignored because the characters now appear left to right, instead of right to left.

Answer (score 1):

**Using JavaScript**

**Remove** `justify-content: flex-end;` and **add** `overflow-x: scroll;` to `#display-text`

Then you can use JavaScript to make the div scroll all the way to the right by default.

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("display-text");
objDiv.scrollLeft = objDiv.scrollWidth;
```

**Using CSS only**

Just using CSS this is possible by **removing** `justify-content: flex-end;` and **add** `overflow-x: scroll;`, `flex-direction: row-reverse` and `direction: ltr;` to `#display-text`

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  It behaves exactly as I had wanted it to.  Out of curiosity, is there any way to do this using only CSS?

Comment: Yes there is, please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/metaDesign/Lukzw0f5/19/), using flex-direction and direction properties - **Answer edited**